# Why does appending to a dict alter the first list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to create a dictionary where each key is a trial identification name and the associated values are a list with a number of elements as integers i.e. {'a':[1,3,4,2,1], 'b':[34,5,3,23]}. I figured I would start with some dummy data and when I use for loops and append(), it makes changes directly to my original data. I have determined that this happens when I try to add to my dict, but don't understand why.

My dummy values and code are as follows:

```
plane1 = [1,1,1]
plane2 = [2,2,2]
plane3 = [3,3,3]
plane4 = [4,4,4]
zList = [plane1,plane2,plane3,plane4]
trial_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

roi_dict = {}

for trial in trial_list:
    print(trial)
    for z in zList:
        if trial not in roi_dict.keys():
            roi_dict[str(trial)] = z
        else:
            roi_dict[str(trial)].append(z)
```

With the final roi_dict being

`{'a': [1, 1, 1, [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]], 'b': [1, 1, 1, [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]], 'c': [1, 1, 1, [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]}`

and

```
print(z_list[0])
[1, 1, 1, [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```

I don't understand why A) the first three elements of the key are individual numbers while the following ones are a list.
B) Why the values aren't [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4] for each key.
C) Why this alters the first value of func_list.

If I should split this into multiple questions I would be more than happy to, but I feel that these all probably stem from the same issue.

Thank you!

Comment: You could try `roi_dict[str(trial)] = [z]` but without this being a [mre] I vote to close needing debugging details.

Comment: I apologize! Yes, I have been working on this trying to parse it apart but realized my variable names were mostly single letters in an incomprehensible form to anyone else looking at it, so I changed l1 to plane1 etc. and func_list to zList. Thank you for pointing that out, I should have read through it more carefully.

Comment: Anyway, you are *always re-using the same lists*. You *alter those lists here*: `.append(z)`. That's why they are altered. The reason they look wrong is because first you add the list itself as the value, e.g. `roi_dict[str(trial)] = z` and then you *append to that list*. So consider, `lst1 = [1,2,3]; lst2 = [4,5,6]; dct = {'a':lst1}; dct['a'].append(lst2)`

Comment: So, it isn't clear to me what you are actually trying to accomplish. What is the result you *wanted*?

Comment: I would like roi_dict to return {'a': [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], 'b': [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], 'c': [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]} with the intention to use this to eventually find the number of neurons in each plane, per trial. Thank you for your previous comments as well!

Comment: @mmartin That isn't a valid Python literal, are those supposed to be lists of lists? In that case, you just want something like: `{trial:[z.copy() for z in zList] for trial in trial_list}` Note, I used `.copy` here because I assume you will be mutating the objects, thus you probably want seperate objects, not the same objects. Otherwise, it would be something like `{trial: zList for trial in trial_list}`, but again, now each `trial` is paired to the same list of lists. Python never implicitly creates copies of an object, you have to copy things explicitly.

Comment: Regarding that last point, check out: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: So, fundamentally, when you ask "Why does appending to a dict alter the first list?" well, *you aren't appending to a dict*. You are appending to a list, that is a value in the dict. And **it is the same list**. So, this is no more mysterious than `x = zList[0]; x.append(42); print(zList[0])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you very much! That was a tremendously helpful explanation. I had seen that nedbatchelder link earlier today and it got me trying .copy() but I kept having the same issue so after banging my head against the wall/this problem all morning I finally put this question up, and it has been edifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zList` is a list of list. You do

> ```
>  if trial not in roi_dict.keys():
>     roi_dict[str(trial)] = z           # z being intem from zList
> else:
>     roi_dict[str(trial)].append(z)
> ```

meaning you set `roi_dict[str(trial)]` to be `z`.

Then you append to `roi_dict[str(trial)]` - list are used by referencing so you essentially `roi_dict[str(trial)]` == `z` and by that you modify `zList[0]` when modifying `roi_dict[str(trial)].append(z)` in further iterations.

Change your code to

```
import copy

 if trial not in roi_dict.keys():
    roi_dict[str(trial)] = [copy.deepcopy(z)]
 else:
    roi_dict[str(trial)].append(z)
```

To fix both porblems.

Comment: @juanpa no need for deepcopy if the original lists really contain integers - then you could do `roi_dict[str(trial)] = [z[:]]` but it said this is simplified.

Answer (score 0):

A) Because the first time you assign to this key you set it to the list [1, 1, 1] that means `roi_dict["a"] = [1, 1, 1]`. But for subsequent loops, you append a list to this list instead of setting to the dict entry. That means that on your second loop it becomes `roi_dict["a"] = [1, 1, 1, [2, 2, 2]]`.

B) If you want this, you need to set

```
roi_dict["a"] = [1, 1, 1]
roi_dict["b"] = [2, 2, 2]
```

etc. In a for loop:

```
for z, trial in zip(zList, trial_list):
     roi_dict[trial] = z
```

C) Because everything in python is a pointer. I.e.: when you assign a list to a dictionary entry, any reference to this dict entry will be pointed to the original list. In other words:

```
>> l = []
>> d = {"list": l}
>> d["list"].append(0)
>> print(l)
>> # l = [0] now because we accessed it via the dictionary
```

If you want to avoid this behavior you need to use copy functions to copy data instead of creating references.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very informative!